# Unable to install python-pip module

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

**System**:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

**Issue**:

Hi. I am using latest Ubuntu image from a docker library. However, I am unable to  install pip module using

```
apt install python-pip # python2.7
```

I installed python 2.7 after installing `software-properties-common`.

`universe` repository is set for all sources but still no success.

```
add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

`apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure pi isp not already on the image?

Comment: I am not seeing Dockerfle, How the question tag with Docker?

Comment: @Adiii I used docker pull ubuntu.